# How to place two plots next to each other in Julia?

Tags: julia

I want to plot the following line plot and scatter plot side-by-side in Julia. The MWE is given below:

```
using Plots
x = 1:10;
y = rand(10);
plot(x, y)
scatter(x, y)
```

[image]

[image]

But doing it this one shows them one below the other, as seperate plots.

Comment: What do you mean combine? Do you want to overlay them, or place them next to each other? Can you make a sketch of what you expect the final result to look like?

Comment: place next to each other

Comment: Thanks for asking Lyndon... I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: With  ```layout = (1, 2)```  I got the expected result!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `layout = (1, 2)` might help!

```
using Plots
x = 1:10;
y = rand(10);
plot1 = plot(x, y);
plot2 = scatter(x, y);
plot(plot1, plot2, layout = (1, 2), legend = false)
```

[image]