# Making Julia show different plots in different windows

Tags: plot, julia

I want to visualize multiple figures in Julia to compare them, and I want to open two separate figures.

Let's say I want to compare two sets of random numbers in two separate windows.
In MATLAB, this can be easily done with

```
figure(1)
scatter(1:10, rand(10,1))

figure(2)
scatter(1:10, rand(10,1))
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695669/how-to-place-two-plots-next-to-each-other-in-julia) describes how to place the plots next to each other in Julia. For example, the following code does that.

```
using Plots
p1 = plot(LinRange(1,10,10),rand(10))
p2 = plot(LinRange(1,10,10),rand(10))
plot(p1,p2)
```

Is there any way to open the plots simultaneously in two different windows in Julia, like MATLAB?

If the `Plots` package cannot do that, is there another package that implements this feature?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show Two Plots in Separate Windows Using Plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64022527/show-two-plots-in-separate-windows-using-plots)

Comment: @Shayan No, it does not work. It shows errors. The error is too big to write in this comment.

Comment: Put the first line of the error.

Comment: @Shayan Here is the output https://pastebin.com/g92XMnJe. I did install pyplots (there were no installation errors).

Comment: Did you follow this thread (?) : https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/418

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround can be using the [`PythonPlot`](https://docs.juliaplots.org/stable/backends/#%5BPythonPlot%5D(https://github.com/stevengj/PythonPlot.jl)) backend. It's a drop in replacement for `pyplot`. First, **install** this backend using `] add PythonPlot`. Then continue:

```
julia> using Plots

julia> pythonplot()
Plots.PythonPlotBackend()

julia> p1 = plot(LinRange(1,10,10),rand(10))

julia> p2 = plot(LinRange(1,10,10),rand(10), reuse=false)
```

The output would be:
[image]